# Searching for strings in office documents using YARA

Tags: pcre, yara

Is it possible to create PCRE based Yara rules to identify matching office documents, like .docx, .xls, .ppt, .pdf, etc.?

I am quite new to Yara, and so fascinated to see such a huge buzz around it.
Will be most grateful for all comments, and any examples.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: come on you have 10 posts on the whole stackoverflow tagged with yara... you call that buzz?! :) Looks more like marginal 0.00001% for a very specific task... And indexing office documents is not that task

Comment: @Nikolay ... Considering the quantum of posts on stackoverfliw, I have no argument :)